# Dojo/Dijit Layout - tried to add a banner at the top of an existing layout

Tags: layout, dojo

Please look at these two attempts:

http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testDijitLayout?menuStyle=dijitTest1

http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testDijitLayout?menuStyle=dijitTest2

Test1 doesn't show the body, but the header is correct. 
Test2 shows the body, but the heading/banner is behind the dojo components.

The only difference is that in Test2, I tried to wrap the AccordianContainer and the body container with another generic container:

> <div
>   dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
>   id="bodyContainer">

I found that when the header was totally outside of the Dojo containers, then the spacing/paging/etc... was just a little bit off.  So my assumption was that the whole page should be in the Dojo containers.

I'm trying to come up with the proper layout to show the header and the body. 
I think you can see the structure from the "view source" of the pages.

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Comment: Neither page loads for me. They both have a green box in the top left with "Loading..." in it.

Comment: Hmmm...Is loading fine for me in Firefox 3.5.  What browser are you on?

Comment: I've had cases where NoScript interferes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wrap your original content in another BorderContainer, with the main content in a 'center' region and the banner at the 'top'?

Comment: Isn't that what i did in one of the samples?

Comment: Not really sure... it's hard to follow.  I see a div under your border container without any region.  All children of BC need to have a region.  Is wphead supposed to be your region='top'?